# A question about triangular numbers

Tags: number-theory

A positive integer is called triangular if it can be written as $n(n+1)/2$ for some natural number $n$.

How many pairs $(a,b)$ of triangular numbers are there such that $b\cdot a = 2007$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that $2007=3^2\cdot 223$. Hence we have to solve
$$a\cdot b=\frac{A(A+1)}{2}\cdot \frac{B(B+1)}{2}=3^2\cdot 223.$$
that is
$$A(A+1)B(B+1)=2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 223.$$
where $A,B$ are positive integers.
According to this equation the prime $223$ should divide $A$ or $(A+1)$, or $B$, or $(B+1)$.

What may we conclude?

Comment: We can conclude that there'll be 4 pairs. Am I right?

Comment: and where did the 2^2 come from?

Comment: @Gigi Chuck See my edited answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: @GigiChuck BTW, what are the 4 pairs that you have found?